# Separate exhaust fan from can lights using a double switch

Tags: electrical

GFCI outlet and single switch which currently operates two can lights and an exhaust fan in bathroom.

I would like to separate the lights from the fan using a double switch.

I need help with how to wire this.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the switch/outlet box, and a photo that looks into the light/fan box for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

First, leave the GFCI outlet alone.  Note that there is a warning tape on the outlet; *do not remove it*.

Now, from the unusual wire colors and metal boxes, it's perfectly likely that your wiring uses the **conduit wiring method**. That is a pipe between this box and other accessible junction boxes, ending up in the junction box at the light/fan.  The pipe contains any sensible number of individual THHN wires, which can be chosen for color.  You can add additional THHN wires as you need.

You will find the other end of that yellow wire is up at  the ceiling fan.  You need to add one more wire to that pipe.   As for the color, any will do except white, gray or green.  I recommend orange, alternate blue.

Note that:

- Red is in use as the always-hot (probably to distinguish it from a black-hot circuit nearby)
- Yellow is currently used as the switched-hot up to the fan+lights
- Since this is another switched wire, I like using a color  that is near yellow, that's orange or green, *and you can't use green*.

As for *how* to pull an additional wire into a conduit pipe, that's another question but ask if you have the question!

Comment: So add one orange wire from second switch all the way to the fan and leave everything else connected. Disconnect yellow to the fan as it is now and connect to the new orange. That’s my thinking originally.

Comment: @ScottFriedericks Yup.  *Conduit has its privileges*.